# Prove the following language is regular?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

> Assume $L_1$ is a regular language, and define:
>
> $$L = \{wcv ∈ \{a, b, c\}^* \mid |w|_a + 2|v|_b ≡ 3 \bmod 5, w, v ∈ L_1\}.$$
>
> Show that $L$ is regular.

I first tried to prove by showing that the pumping lemma holds true, then learned that it was not a double implication and can only be used to prove languages are not regular.

Then I tried to draw an NFA, but didn't make any progress.

What's a good way to prove that a language like this is regular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on whether $L_1$ is a language over $\{a,b\}$ or over $\{a,b,c\}$.

**$L_1$ is a language over $\{a,b\}$**

In this case, the easiest way to proceed is using closure operations. Show first (by constructing a DFA) that the following language is regular:
$$
L_2 = \{wcv \mid |w|_a+2|v|_b \equiv 3 \bmod 5 , w,v \in \{a,b\}^*\}.
$$
Your language is $L = L_1cL_1 \cap L_2$.

**$L_1$ is a language over $\{a,b,c\}$**

In this case we have to be more careful. Given a DFA (or an NFA) for $L_1$, we construct one for $L$ which in three stages:

1. Simulate $L_1$ and keep track of the number of $a$s modulo 5. Whenever at an accepting state of $L_1$, add a nondeterministic move to stage 2.
2. Read $c$.
3. Simulate $L_1$ (starting from its initial state again) and keep track of the number of $b$s modulo 5. A state is accepting if it is accepting for $L_1$ and the constraint $|w|_a+2|v|_b$ is satisfied, where $w$ is the word read at the first stage, and $v$ is the word read at the third stage.

I'll let you fill in the details.

Answer (score 1):

For every $i=0,\dots,4$, there exists a regular expression $W_i$ for the language of all words $w$ such that $|w|_a \bmod 5 = i$.

For example:
$$
((b+c)^*a)^i  ( ((b+c)^*a)^5)^*(b+c)^*
$$

Similarly, for every $j=0,\dots,4$, there exists a regular expression $Z_j$ for the language of all words $z$ such that $2|z|_b \bmod 5 = j$.

Then a regular expression for your language is $\sum_{i=0}^4 W_i c Z_{(3-i) \bmod 5}$